# sql server - iterate each columns data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Sample data :**

```
LINE_NO E_FIELD F_FIELD G_FIELD HSA_STATUS  FAMILY  CACHE_FAMILY    Count
23053B  00000   00000   00000   S           SUMMIT      WER           43
23053B  00000   00000   00000   T           SUMMIT      WER           144
23053B  00000   00000   00684   T           SUMMIT      WER           2
23053B  00353   00418   00684   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   00763   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   01512   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   06797   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   30228   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  00353   00418   31935   T           SUMMIT      WER           2
23053B  05601   01402   00758   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  05601   01402   09091   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
23053B  05601   01402   65053   T           SUMMIT      WER           1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
23054B 00000 00000 00000 S                 SUMMIT      WER           37   
23054B 00000 00000 00000 T                 SUMMIT      WER           96    
23054B 00353 00418 00758 T                 SUMMIT      WER           1    
23054B 00354 00414 01095 T                  SUMMIT     WER           1
```

This is my query:
"
**SELECT LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY,Count = ((SUM(TOTAL)) )  FROM(
SELECT LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY, Count(LINE_NO) as Total FROM TX_HSA_SUMM 
WHERE MT_TIMESTAMP2 BETWEEN ('2013-03-07 10:10:00') AND ('2013-03-08 10:20:00') 
GROUP BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY) as a
GROUP BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY,total
ORDER BY LINE_NO,E_FIELD,F_FIELD,G_FIELD,HSA_STATUS,FAMILY,CACHE_FAMILY,total"**

This is my sample data actually. I already make the count. As You can see the column header. My problem is I need to sum the count and the for each row I need to get the percentage. For example the total for the above record is **199** so for the first record count is **43** so the calculation should be **43/199 * 100**. How can I view the percentage? The ?? mean column to get percentage. Please help me I need this urgently.it should be done only for that particular line line after the dash its a new line no so when calculating the percentage it should count only that particular line no count and get the percentage.

Is there any suggestion to show how to get the count first. then from that sum the count and finally. the count should be divided with the sum and * 100 to get percentage. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the sql query? What version of sql-server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following query :

```
select (Count/(select SUM(Count) from tablename))*100 from tablename;
```

Here the `SUM()` is used to find the sum of the values in the column.

As mentioned in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) SUM can be used with numeric columns only. Null values are ignored.

Comment: Im getting this error Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Invalid column name 'Count'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Invalid column name 'Count'.

Comment: Again having some error Msg 409, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The sum or average aggregate operation cannot take a varchar data type as an argument.
Msg 403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals divide, type equals varchar.

Comment: if so use `SELECT CONVERT(INT, Count) FROM Tablename` to convert the `varchar` to `int` before using `sum()`

Comment: the count is actually not the column name i just a schema name. count not varchar. the line number is varchar actually.

Comment: I have a doubt that it is in `varchar` format and so not being processed. Can you try this `select (Count/(select SUM(SELECT CONVERT(INT, Count) FROM tablename) from tablename))*100 from tablename;`

Comment: it showing Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Line 3: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0):

An easiest way:
Create a temp table(say @temp) insert your above result into that and do following:

```
Declare @temp table
(
    LINE_NO varchar(20), 
    E_FIELD varchar(20),
    F_FIELD varchar(20),
    G_FIELD varchar(20),
   HSA_STATUS varchar(20),
   FAMILY varchar(20),
   CACHE_FAMILY varchar(20),
   CountValue int
 )
 Insert into @temp
 Your above result shown in your question

Declare @CountSum int
Set @CountSum=(Select Sum(CountValue) From @temp)

Select t.*,Cast(Cast((t.CountValue*@CountSum) as Decimal(10,3))/100 as decimal(5,2))    Count_Percentage From @temp t
```

it will give:

```
LINE_NO E_FIELD F_FIELD G_FIELD HSA_STATUS  FAMILY  CACHE_FAMILY    Count     Count_Percentage
=============================================================================================== 
23053B  00000   00000   00000   S           SUMMIT  WER               43        85.57
23053B  00000   00000   00000   T           SUMMIT  WER              144        286.56
23053B  00000   00000   00684   T           SUMMIT  WER              2          3.98
23053B  00353   00418   00684   T           SUMMIT  WER              1          1.99
23053B  00353   00418   00763   T           SUMMIT  WER              1          1.99
23053B  00353   00418   01512   T           SUMMIT  WER              1          1.99
23053B  00353   00418   06797   T           SUMMIT  WER              1          1.99
23053B  00353   00418   30228   T           SUMMIT  WER              1          1.99
23053B  00353   00418   31935   T           SUMMIT  WER              2          3.98
23053B  05601   01402   00758   T           SUMMIT  WER              1          1.99
23053B  05601   01402   09091   T           SUMMIT  WER              1          1.99
23053B  05601   01402   65053   T           SUMMIT  WER              1          1.99
```

Comment: The percentage calculation is not correct because the 43 should divide with the sum of the count example 43/199 * 100 so the value is 21%. this how it should work actually

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH T AS 
(
    SELECT 43 AS [Count]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 144
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
)

SELECT 100.0 * T.[Count] / SUM(T.[Count]) OVER()
FROM T
```